# react native otp verify erro generateDebugRFile

Tags: react-native, sms, one-time-password

Error building android after installing lib. Version RN >= 0.60

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-otp-verify:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-otp-verify:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-otp-verify

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I also tested by performing the manual linking, but not building too.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        targetSdkVersion = 32
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion   = "16.1.0"
        googlePlayServicesIidVersion = "16.0.1"
        googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "15.0.2"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "21.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
    ....
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
```

android/app/src/buil.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    ...
    }
```

Lib -> https://github.com/faizalshap/react-native-otp-verify
Manual linking -> https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/autolinking.md

Comment: Could you please update your question with your build.gradle files too

Comment: I'm sorry, the project is private. I'm not sure what I could show.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle file shown above is the `android/build.gradle`. One more gradle file is there inside your android app folder please add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'` inside `dependencies` of your `android/app/build.gradle` and try cleaning and rebuilding

Comment: Continue error, did not work

Comment: Try adding `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'` inside `android/build.gradle` dependencies

Comment: I'm almost giving up and looking for another way to get otp message

Comment: I think it is an issue with play services version. In the latest version i have used new apis from google for retrieving phone number from device which makes use of this classes.
Can you try updating the `googlePlayServicesVersion to 20.3.0`

https://github.com/faizalshap/react-native-otp-verify/issues/67